# Keras with Hierarchical LSTM

Tags: keras, deep-learning, hierarchical

I had a problem about hierarchical lstm in keras. It works well when the data is 2 dimensions. When I changed it to three dimensions, it does not work. My data is (25,10,2)
I want to build a hierarchical lstm, the first layer lstm will convert each data with shape (10,2) into a vector, there are 25 vectors feed into the second layer lstm.  The input data in the first layer lstm is (10,2). I used two embeddings and multiply them.  I appreciate if anyone can help.

```
def H_LSTM():
    single_input = Input(shape=(10,2),dtype='int32')
    in_sentence = Lambda(lambda x: single_input[:,:, 0:1], output_shape=(maxlen,))(single_input)
    in_sentence = Reshape((maxlen,), input_shape = (maxlen,1))(in_sentence)
    
    in_drug = Lambda(lambda x: single_input[:, :, 1:1], output_shape=(maxlen,))(single_input)
    in_drug = Reshape((maxlen,), input_shape = (maxlen,1))(in_drug)
    
    embedded_sentence = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=maxlen, trainable=True, mask_zero=False)(in_sentence)    
    embedded_drug = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix],
                                input_length=maxlen, trainable=True, mask_zero=False)(in_drug)
    embedded_sequences = Multiply()([embedded_sentence, embedded_drug])    
    lstm_sentence = LSTM(100)(embedded_sequences)
    encoded_model = Model(inputs = single_input, outputs = lstm_sentence)


    sequence_input = Input(shape=(25,10,2),dtype='int32')
    seq_encoded = TimeDistributed(encoded_model)(sequence_input)
    seq_encoded = Dropout(0.2)(seq_encoded)
    # Encode entire sentence
    seq_encoded = LSTM(100)(seq_encoded)
    # Prediction
    prediction = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(seq_encoded)
    model = Model(inputs = sequence_input, outputs = prediction)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='rmsprop',
                  metrics=['acc'])
    

    return model
```

Model Summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 10, 2)        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)               (None, 10)           0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_4 (Lambda)               (None, 10)           0           input_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_3 (Reshape)             (None, 10)           0           lambda_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_4 (Reshape)             (None, 10)           0           lambda_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_3 (Embedding)         (None, 10, 128)      4895744     reshape_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_4 (Embedding)         (None, 10, 128)      4895744     reshape_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
multiply_2 (Multiply)           (None, 10, 128)      0           embedding_3[0][0]                
                                                                 embedding_4[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                   (None, 100)          91600       multiply_2[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 9,883,088
Trainable params: 9,883,088
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         (None, 25, 10, 2)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 25, 100)           9883088   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 25, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 202       
=================================================================
Total params: 9,963,690
Trainable params: 9,963,690
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Error Message:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_3' with dtype int32 and shape [?,10,2]
     [[node input_3 (defined at D:\Users\Jinhe.Shi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_6214]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Update: the framework is shown in the following, the difference is no attention layer and I added two embeddings in the lower layer lstm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0kjw.png)

Model fit:

The error happens during the model fitting.

```
model2 = H_LSTM();
print("model fitting - Hierachical network")
model2.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=3, batch_size=100, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

The input data likes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q95Vv.png)

Comment: is there any reason why you create 2 separate models encoded_model and model, can u put all together?

Comment: The reason is the first model encoded_model is called during the second model.  seq_encoded = TimeDistributed(encoded_model)(sequence_input). Each timestep will call the encoded_model. I don't know how to put them together. I will add model figure in updates.

Comment: Does the error happen when compiling the model or when feeding data in? If latter - could you post a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you feed some mock data into your model?

Comment: @mjarosie, the error happens during model fit. I updated the input data shape